# textbox, combobox in WPF listview

Tags: wpf, listview, combobox, textbox

I am porting an application from foxpro to C#.Net. This is a wine shop billing software. Its billing interface screenshot link is here http://picasaweb.google.com/raj.kishor09/RAJK?feat=directlink

But my client wants similar interface on WPF too. I think listview can help me in this regard but don't know how to implement. i figured out that each row of listview should have 2 textbox, 1 combobox and few textblock or label.

Not only this but cursor should jump from one control to other control using "Enter/Return" key instead of "Tab" key.

Please help me with some code lines.

Please guys help me......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the ListView like you mention. it's not that hard.

Consider this :

You listview will now contains 2 textboxes. I suggest you test a little with something like this. The key point is to define your ItemsTemplate the way you need it.